# Fill missing user input with zeros

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading

I have a function that parses user input into the correct overloaded function. My "parseUserInput" function determines if the user entered a character, a floating-point, or an integer array. Then it calls the overloaded function to ultimately determine the average grade. The problem I am facing is, when I enter an integer array, I want to ensure if the user doesn't enter 5 integers, that the rest get filled in with zeros.

Example: "55 66 98 32 87" would work.

Example: "55 66" would not work... I want the compiler to understand the missing variables should be auto-filled to zero, such as .... " 55 66 0 0 0".

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

```
   void parseUserInput(char *userInput)
    {
        int array[ASSGN_MARK];
    
        /* other code ... */
    
        else if (sscanf(userInput, "%i %i %i %i %i", &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3], &array[4]))
        {
            printf(">> This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(int[]) >> function ...\n");
            assessGrade(array);
        }
    
       /* other code...*/
   }



//Overloaded Function
void assessGrade(int array[ASSGN_MARK])
{
    int total = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    

    sum = array[0] + array[1] + array[2] + array[3] + array[4];

    total = sum / ASSGN_MARK;

    //being type-casted to a double, as I'm calling the next overloaded function
    //and that overloaded function will display if the student passed or failed
    assessGrade((double)total);
}
```

Comment: The values in `int array[ASSGN_MARK];` are uninitialised, which is why the code may not work.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a C++ question, I recommend you do it the C++ way, and use std::vector.  You can initialize the elements to zero like this:

```
std::vector < int > array(5, 0);
```

You'll also need to pass a reference, create a class to put both functions in, or make it global, because the way you have it right now, the other function can't see array.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use a vector. Do you think there's a way to have some sort of `If statement` that says if that array element is empty, copy a zero into that element placeholder?

Comment: I'd do it with a for loop, based on the return value of scanf().  You shouldn't come here and ask others to do your homework for you.  It impairs your learning.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to make these two functions work..

First, I've changed my function prototype to use default parameters. Therefore, if the user doesn't enter a number the number gets defaulted to 0.

```
    void parseUserInput(char *userInput)
    {
            /* other code... */

        else if (sscanf(userInput, "%i %i %i %i %i", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e))
        {
            printf(">> This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(int[]) >> function ...\n");
            assessGrade(a, b, c, d, e);
        }
            /* other code... */
    }
        
        
    void assessGrade(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
    {
         int total = 0;
         int sum = 0;
        
         sum = a + b + c + d + e;
        
         total = sum / 5;
        
         assessGrade((double)total);
    
    }
```